# Refreshing an image in a Gtk# window, after a certain amount of time the image disappears

Tags: c#, .net, gtk#

I'm writing a simple app using C#, .Net 4.5 and Gtk# that captures a portion of the screen and loads it onto a image in a window. After a few seconds the image disappears and I get the following error :

Glib-CRITICAL **: Source ID xxxx was not found when attempting to remove it.

Relevant code:

**Program.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dota2Trainer
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gtk.Application.Init();
            MiniMapOverlay myWin = new MiniMapOverlay();
            myWin.KeepAbove = true;
            //myWin.Decorated = false;
            myWin.Resize(200, 200);
            myWin.ShowAll();
            ScreenCapturer screenCap = new ScreenCapturer(30, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, myWin);
            screenCap.Start();
            Gtk.Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**MiniMapOverlay.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using Gtk;

namespace Dota2Trainer
{
    public partial class MiniMapOverlay : Gtk.Window
    {
        Gtk.Image image = null;
        public MiniMapOverlay() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
        {
            image = new Gtk.Image();
            var buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(".\\image0.jpeg");
            var pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(buffer);
            image.Pixbuf = pixbuf;
            this.Add(image);
            this.Build();
        }

        public void RefreshImage(byte[] buffer)
        {
            try
            {
                var pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(buffer);
                image.Pixbuf = pixbuf;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenCapturer.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;

namespace Dota2Trainer
{
    public delegate void OnSavedImage(byte[] screenCap);
    public class ScreenCapturer
    {
        public System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        int interval= 30000;
        readonly int screenWidth;
        readonly int screenHeight;
        Rectangle bounds;
        const double miniMapWidthPercentage = 0.15;
        const double miniMapHeightPercentage = 0.25;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        bool Busy = false;
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        public OnSavedImage onSaveImage;

        public ScreenCapturer(int interval, int screenWidth, int screenHeight, MiniMapOverlay imageHolder)
        {
            this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
            this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
            this.interval = interval;
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = this.interval;
            int miniMapWidth = (int)(screenWidth * miniMapWidthPercentage);
            int miniMapHeight = (int)(screenHeight * miniMapHeightPercentage);
            int miniMapStartWidth = (screenWidth - miniMapWidth);
            int miniMapStartHeight = (screenHeight - miniMapHeight);

            bounds = new Rectangle(miniMapStartWidth, miniMapStartHeight, miniMapWidth, miniMapHeight);
            bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
            onSaveImage += imageHolder.RefreshImage;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Busy)
                    return;
                Busy = true;
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                    onSaveImage((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[])));
                }
                Busy = false;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full source code can be found here:

https://github.com/oldtimerza/Dota2Trainer

How it works is simply creates a timer , that after a certain amount of time runs the OnTimedEvent() method of the Screencapturer class, which has a delegate that will run the MiniMapOverlay RefreshImage() method. The code is shocking at the moment, but I just wanted to get a rough and ready version up and running before I refactor it.

I've been searching for ages as to why this happens, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to want to parse your entire project, please post the relevant parts of your source code related to the issue.

Comment: Project only consists of 3 small classes, I've just included their source code to remove the need to visit the git page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Glib.Timeout` instead of `System.Timers`. There can be threading issues with `System.Timers` and the timer event occurs on a different thread than the GTK application. `Glib.Timeout` queues an event in the main GTK application loop at a certain interval, and runs in the same thread. However, its not suitable for time sensitive functions because the application loop is handling other events such as mouse clicks. I've seen delays of around a half second to a second, but that was on an older computer while debugging. This doesn't seem to be an issue for your application; just for future reference. Also, `Glib.Timeout` will keep calling the update event until you return false.

```
uint timerId;

public void Start(uint interval)
{
    timerId = GLib.Timeout.Add (interval, OnUpdateTimer);
}

protected bool OnUpdateTimer ()
{
    try
    {
        if (Busy)
            return;
        Busy = true;
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            onSaveImage((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[])));
        }
        Busy = false;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with threading. Thanks. Just a small side note that the "if(Busy) return;" section needs to return a bool.